# Jquery scroll to element just goes to top of page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, scrollto

I have some JQuery that updates my page content via Ajax (paging through some sub table content) and I want the page to "jump" (scroll) back to the top of the section where the content has just been updated. I found some code to try and perform the scroll but it only ever goes right back to the top of the page and not to the specific element :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".page-number").on("click", function() {
            var page = parseInt($(this).html());
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ProductReview")',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    "id": @Model.Product.ProductID,
                    "page": page
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#review-list").html(data);
                    $("#page-number-"+ page).addClass("selected");
                    //location.hash = "#prodreviews";
                    scrollToAnchor("prodreviews");
                }
            });
        });
        // scroll handler
        var scrollToAnchor = function(id) {
            // grab the element to scroll to based on the name
            var elem = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");
            // if that didn't work, look for an element with our ID
            if (typeof(elem.offset()) === "undefined") {
                elem = $("#"+id);
            }
            //alert(elem.offset().top);
            // if the destination element exists
            if (typeof(elem.offset()) !== "undefined") {
                // do the scroll
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: elem.offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

This is within an Asp.net MVC Partial View that reloads itself into the main razor view when paging links are clicked - that works fine. I have the following anchor near the top of this partial view :

```
<a name="prodreviews" id="prodreviews"></a>
```

And my paging links within same partial view are :

```
<div class="pagewrapper">
@for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Reviews.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    <a class="page-number" id="page-number-@i" href="javascript:void(0)">@i</a>
}
</div>
```

Is it because the anchor is rendered again when the Ajax fires? I tried moving it into the main razor view but then the jQuery code didn't seem to be able to find it at all (despite the fact is should be in the DOM?)

I can see when the anchor is back in the partial view and when the alert is un-remmed that it does find the element and return a negative figure which is because it's the offset from where I am currently? Is the page then trying to scroll to that absolute point, rather than back to where I want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/49opng69/) — `.animate()` works fine.

Make sure the `#prodreviews` element exists on the page, and give it some CSS styling so you can visually identify it on the page. Additionally, if the page contains [floating elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) above the `#prodreviews` tag, ensure it is `clear`ed.

Open up Developer Tools in your web browser and check the Console for other JavaScript errors, that may be preventing this specific code from running.

Comment: Hmm it was when my anchor was empty it didn't work - I added a non breaking space and it fixed it. I have changed it now though and just targeted the outer div wrapper for the section, and also simplified it using your scroll code - many thanks.